# Issue regarding syncing aws amplify datastore with local mysql database

Tags: reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

While creating an application, I’m using AWS amplify datastore where I have created data models. I have created a react application & developed using AWS amplify. How to give a database connection to my front-end react code? Please help me.

I have graphql api with me. But I don't know how to fetch data from input fields in the front-end & validate the data.

Someone, please help me

I have tried to create data models in aws amplify. I have added api using “amplify add API”. I have a signup page, where we capture firstname, lastname, mobileno, city, and state. I wanted to register my account with these fields & these data should go & be stored in AWS amplify datastore

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at which point you are stuck, so I strongly advise you to take the time to go through the Amplify sample application which covers data storage in detail.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/

Comment: How to use graphql api for fetching input fields data